# cannot read string result from MYSQL

Tags: if-statement, arraylist, android-asynctask, marker

I want to have an if else statement inside a loop when getting the results of 
data from mysql .. However the if statement cannot read the result.. but the codes are perfectly
 I see the problem in my if else condition.

here is my Code from my asynctask

```
for (int i = 0; i < markers.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = markers.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    Double LAT = c.getDouble(TAG_LAT);
                    Double LNG = c.getDouble(TAG_LNG);
                    String color = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);

                   String red = "ongoing"; 
                    String green = "firedout"; 

                    if (color == red){
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(LAT, LNG);
                    status.add(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(color)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                    .position(position));
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    }

                    if (color == green){
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(LAT, LNG);
                        status.add(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(color)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                        .position(position));
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        }

                }
```

Comment: I think your if condition miss something.do some thing like this                     if (color == "green")

Comment: i thought so of that one.. when i remove the if statement.. my title is getting the status.. and markers were added in the map with their corresponding titles

Comment: no it does not work.. the data stored in my database are basically "ongoing" and "firedout" only.. so if the result is ongoing, the color of the marker must be red then if result is firedout, it must be green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalent `String` values are not guaranteed to be unique in Java. In other words, there can be two `String` objects with exactly the same value.

```
String s1 = "ongoing";
String s2 = new String(s1);
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // false!
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); // true :)
```

Therefore, you must say:

```
if (red.equals(color)) {
    // do something
}
```